# Displaying JSON Data from Public Endpoint via jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, endpoint

I am trying to output the JSON data from this endpoint:

[UPDATE] Header values:

- X-HostChannel = BACKOFFICE
- Accept = application/json
- Content-Type = application/json

[image]

My attempt in doing this uses jQuery AJAX:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://ecomm-bo-asia.makdev.intra-apps.com/backoffice-api/dashboards/payout-time",
        accept: "application/json",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonp: false,
        beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('X-HostChannel', 'BACKOFFICE');}
      }).then(function(data) {
        $('.widget-value-container').append(data.d1value);
      });
    });
```

For some reason however, I'm getting this error when I run it:

> `GET` https://ecomm-bo-asia.makdev.intra-apps.com/backoffice-api/dashboards/payout-time?_=1448948142741
>   `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500`
>   `(Internal Server Error)`

Am I missing something? Also, I am not sure what to place in the jsonCallback parameter, hence not including them here. Where do I find this? Am I missing something to make this work? This is working in Post Man FYI.

Comment: the actual parameter name is `accept` and not `accepts`. Also because you're sending a `GET`, you can remove the `contentType` param.

Comment: is this url published in web ?

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh Corrected the code already and removed the `contentType` param. Still gives out status 500 error on `GET`

Comment: @KishoreSahas On my limited knolwedge, I was informed that the endpoint is now "public" removing any authentication for easy access.

Comment: the url contains `https` scheme. Are you sure it's not `http`?

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh `https://` is required to access this endpoint.